# how do i change the shape color when the mouse pointer is exactly inside the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

i am facing one problem which is when my mouse pointer near the shape,the shape's background color already started to change.i couldn't find any info about this problem from online.sorry,i could not paste the screenshot here, please look at the jsfiddle link below.
i think my question is not so clear, i want to change the shape color when the mouse cursor over it,now the problem is when my mouse cursor near the shape , it is already changed to white color, how to do like when the mouse cursor is exactly in the blue area then the color will change to white. thanks! –

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");

//Begin our drawing
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.lineTo(150, 300);
ctx.lineTo(0, 150);

//Define the style of the shape
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,173,239)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 50, 200)";

//Close the path
ctx.closePath();

//Fill the path with ourline and color
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
myCanvas.addEventListener("mouseover", hover, false);
myCanvas.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOut, false);

function hover(e) {
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 50, 200)";
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
}

function hoverOut(e) {
  var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,173,239)";
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: black solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/un22earx/) link of my code. thanks!!

Comment: can you explain it more what you want.

Comment: hi,i think my question is not so clear, i want to change the shape color when the mouse cursor over it,now the problem is when my mouse cursor near the shape , it is already changed to white color, how to do like when the mouse cursor is exactly in the blue area then the color will change to white. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is using `mousemove` event and [ctx.isPointInPath()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) method.

The concept is checking if the current mouse point is in the path(**the last defined path, or you can create a `Path2d` object**) when the cursor is moving on the canvas.

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
var pointInfo = document.getElementById("pointInfo");

//Begin our drawing
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(150, 0);
ctx.lineTo(300, 150);
ctx.lineTo(150, 300);
ctx.lineTo(0, 150);
//Close the path
ctx.closePath();

//Define the style of the shape
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,173,239)";
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 50, 200)";

//Fill the path with ourline and color
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();

// bind listener
myCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", check, false);

function check(e) {

  // get the current mouse point
  var pointX = e.offsetX;
  var pointY = e.offsetY;
  
  // make the canvas blank first
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, myCanvas.width, myCanvas.height);
  
  // check if the mouse point is in the path which is defined at line 4 to line 11
  if (ctx.isPointInPath(pointX, pointY)) { // in
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 50, 200)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  } else { // out
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,173,239)";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  
  // show point info in the page
  pointInfo.textContent = "Mouse Point: (" + pointX + ', ' + pointY + ')';
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: black solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pointInfo">Mouse Point: </div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a shape inside the canvas and you want to change the background of that shape when user hover on the shape, not on the canvas. Correct? 
Alternate way of doing this is to create a canvas of this shape. You can achieve this by using CSS transformations. You can check out this link for the [css transformation](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) here.

Comment: hi,i think my qustion not so clear, i want to change the shape color,when the mouse hover it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is change BG color if mouse hover exactly over the shape. As of now your "hover" and "hoverout" function are pointing to whole canvas. That's why BG color is changing on hover inside the  canvas itself.

To get your desired functionality you can try these two ways:

1. Defined the Line boundaries to detect if the mouse pointer is inside the shape or not. [A Demo for defining path](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/Cw4ZN/)
2. You can also defined the shape outer lines as a boundaries to detect your mouse position and then execute your functionality. [A Demo for defining path boundaries](http://jsfiddle.net/yXVrk/1/)

I hope you get an idea to modify your code. For any doubt or further help please comment below. 
Thanks

First fiddle concept

```
function linepointNearestMouse(line,x,y) {
lerp=function(a,b,x){ return(a+x*(b-a)); };
var dx=line.x1-line.x0;
var dy=line.y1-line.y0;
var t=((x-line.x0)*dx+(y-line.y0)*dy)/(dx*dx+dy*dy);
var lineX=lerp(line.x0, line.x1, t);
var lineY=lerp(line.y0, line.y1, t);
return({x:lineX,y:lineY});
};
```

second fiddle concept.

```
function init() {
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var bigGreen = new BigCircle(ctx,50, 50, '#5eb62b', 50);
$('#canvas').click(function(e){
var x = e.clientX
  , y = e.clientY          
if(Math.pow(x-50,2)+Math.pow(y-50,2) < Math.pow(50,2))   
  bigGreen.clicked()
})    
}
```

Visit the JS fiddle to get the exact  functionality.